# Why the phase response of a series RLC circuit plotted against frequency goes from 100 to -100 degree?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPnm4j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function which is $$\frac{Vo}{Vi}=\frac{R}{R+j(\omega L-\frac{1}{\omega C})}$$

The phase is $$-arctan(\frac{\omega L-\frac{1}{\omega C}}{R})$$

[image]

**My question is why is the phase going to 100 degree when $$\omega<<\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$? How can you see it from the phase equation?**

The phase equation can re-writtened as $$\frac{\omega^2LC-1}{\omega RC}$$. When omega^2LC<<1. the phase is basically $$-arctan(-\frac{1}{\omega RC})$$. Why is this equal to 100 degree?

Comment: Where did you see this? Are you sure it's 100 degrees and not 90 degrees?

Comment: You know you can simulate this circuit directly in your browser, from circuitlab, where you drew the circuit in the first place? I think you will find that the phase indeed goes from 90 to -90, not 100 to -100.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the phase response of a series RLC circuit plotted against
>   frequency goes from 100 to -100 degree?

It doesn't.

It goes from +90 degrees to -90 degrees.

At very low frequencies XC is very high and XL is virtually zero hence the circuit can be regarded as a series capacitor and a load resistor: -

[image]
[image]

At very high frequencies XL is very high and XC is virtually zero hence the circuit can be regarded as a series inductor and a load resistor: -

[image]
[image]

[Source of pictures](http://www.play-hookey.com/ac_theory/filters/lo_pass_filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're looking at:

$$\mathcal{A}:=\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right)=\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}-\frac{\text{j}}{\omega\text{C}}}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)\cdot\text{j}}\right)=\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}^2-\text{R}\cdot\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)\cdot\text{j}}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}^2}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}-\frac{\text{R}\cdot\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}\cdot\text{j}\right)\tag1$$

And that is NOT always equal to the vaule of the phase you stated.

---

Let's say:

1. \$\text{R}^2>\text{R}\cdot\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)\$:
   $$\mathcal{A}=-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}}{\text{R}}\right)\tag2$$
2. \$\text{R}^2<\text{R}\cdot\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)\$:
   $$\mathcal{A}=\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}}{\text{R}}\right)-\pi\tag3$$